# Can't refresh Google API token in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I am trying to work with the Google Calendar API in my Rails(5.2.1) app but am having real trouble with the refresh token--my understanding of which is tenuous at best, even after having gone through quite a bit of documentation.

Here is my code:

```
          class CalendarsController < ApplicationController

              def authorize
                client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
                redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
              end

              def callback
                client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
                client.code = params[:code]

                response = client.fetch_access_token!

                session[:authorization] = response

                redirect_to root_url
              end

              def get_calendars
                client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
                client.update!(session[:authorization])
                client.update!(
  additional_parameters: {
    access_type: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent'
  }
)
                service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
                service.authorization = client
                # here is my attempt to refresh
                begin
                  service.list_calendar_lists
                    rescue Google::Apis::AuthorizationError
                      response = client.refresh!
                      session[:authorization] = session[:authorization].merge(response)
                      retry
                end
              end

              def new
                all_calendars = get_calendars.items
                @calendar_list = all_calendars.select {|calendar| calendar.access_role=="owner"}
           end

          def client_options
            {
              client_id: Rails.application.credentials.web[:client_id],
              client_secret: Rails.application.credentials.web[:client_secret],
              authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent',
              token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
              scope: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR,
              redirect_uri: callback_url
            }
          end
    end
```

If I go to the URL that leads to `#authorize` I am directed to an OAuth screen and asked for permission to access my calendars.  Once granted, the app works as expected.  After an hour, the token expires and I can't get it to refresh.  You can see my attempt above:  Without that attempt, I get a `Google::Apis::AuthorizationError`.  With it, I get "Missing authorization code."  I'm totally lost and am having trouble following the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is quite challenging, and the error messages don't help much!

You're not showing the `client_options` that are being passed in, and since everything else looks correct - I'm guessing this is where the problem lies. Are you setting the `access_type` parameter for offline access, so that you can actually refresh the token without the user having to re-authenticate?

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer):

> Set the value to offline if your application needs to refresh access
>   tokens when the user is not present at the browser. This is the method
>   of refreshing access tokens described later in this document. This
>   value instructs the Google authorization server to return a refresh
>   token and an access token the first time that your application
>   exchanges an authorization code for tokens.

You can do this in the `authorization_uri`. For example:

```
client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
  client_id: ...,
  client_secret: ...,
  authorization_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent",
  scope: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR,
  redirect_uri: callback_url
})
```

Or when calling `update!`:

```
client.update!(
  additional_parameters: {
    access_type: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent'
  }
)
```

Comment: Can you mark the part "offline" as code since it also is in the documentation you've quoted. It also helps to differentiate between a state and actual value. Since it's only a two char diff I can't add it myself.

Comment: @gwcodes I made the improvements you suggested but still getting the same error.  I don't quite understand the 'refresh' part (what's the point of a token expiring if it automatically refreshes?).  I'd be happy if when navigating to my home page, the app just redirected to authorization if there was an error (which I tried in the code above) but I just get that "Missing authorization token" error